# ECO B40 game for analysis

Tags: opening, analysis, sicilian-defense, french-defense

Here is the game pgn,

```
[fen ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2017.02.15"]
[Round "?"]
[White "johnybravo001"]
[Black "anandsadasivam"]
[Result "0-1"]
[ECO "B40"]
[WhiteElo "827"]
[BlackElo "829"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[Termination "anandsadasivam won by checkmate"]
[CurrentPosition "r5k1/pb4p1/1p1b2r1/2p2Q1N/6PP/2PP1P2/7q/1NR2RK1 w - - 3 25"]

1.e4 e6 2.Nf3 c5 3.Bc4 Nc6 4.d3 Qf6 5.Bg5 Qxb2 6.Nbd2 Nf6 7.Bxf6 Qxf6 8.h4 h5 9.Ng5 Nb4 10.O-O Qc3 11.Rc1 Nxa2 12.Bxa2 b6 13.Qe1 Bb7 14.f3 f6 15.Nb1 Qb2 16.Bxe6 dxe6 17.Nxe6 Ke7 18.Nf4 Rh6 19.c3 Kf7 20.e5 fxe5 21.Qxe5 Kg8 22.Nxh5 Rg6 23.g4 Bd6 24.Qf5 Qh2#  0-1
```

Here is the fen diagram of end game,

```
[fen "r5k1/pb4p1/1p1b2r1/2p2Q1N/6PP/2PP1P2/7q/1NR2RK1 w - - 3 25"]
```

Assume, `24.Qf4!` or `24.Qg3!` is played, what could be the further game. Please analyze further considering either of this move is been played.

As part of the game, it progressed better maybe few blunders or maybe the kind of swindle. My concern is not about that. I need further analysis as if the check mate avoided by my opponent. However you comment or scribble about the game.

And please name this ECO B40 game name. My Android phone says `French Sicilian Defense`. And to say it is not exact ECO B40, as there is swap of moves, I had started French Defense by the fact.

Comment: If white plays either 24.Qf4 or 24.Qg3, black just takes the queen, with a trivially won game. There is nothing to analyse whatsover after that. And why are you so obsessed with the name of the opening? It's a French Sicilian, since you play e6-c5 in the two opening moves. This will not help you improve at all at your current level.

Comment: Yep! Ok. Let me try with even irregular openings other than the standard ones. Thanks for your suggestion on opening, I had grasped all at once in a long back at wiki. I am yet not that proficient that I well know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should really not get obsessed with opening theory at your level. Just make natural moves that develop pieces and occupy the center. Learn general principles first which will help you more than if you learn an opening. In any case your opponent got out of any theory already on the third move (3. Bc4), so opening theory won't help you.

Not a bad game from your side, except for the blunder of the knight on move 11. My analysis:

- After 1.e4 e6 2.Nf3 c5 you have what is called the *Sicilian defense, French variation*, which usually appears after 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 e6 (black avoiding the possibility of the French defense in this move order).
- 3. Bc4; not the best move, since unlike in say the Italian game the bishop does not attack much on f7. Also the bishop could easily be kicked away by pawns playing either 3...d5 immediately or after 3...a6. The most popular/best move is 3. d4
- 3. ... Nc6, ok move, but here or in the following moves you should really consider playing a6, b5 (developing the bishop to b7 later) or d5, taking advantage of the misplaced bishop on c4 which you can attack a tempo.
- 4 ... Qf6, don't get out the queen that early. It could easily get attacked and does not threaten anything from f6 either. Develop your pieces, likely the bishop to e7, knight to f6....
- 11 ... Nxa2?? blunders the knight in one move
- 14 f3 seriously weakens the dark squares in the white camp, particularly since white does not have a dark squared bishop anymore. Black should focus on how to take advantage of this.
- 15 ... Qb2? allows white to get two pawns for a piece. After 15... Qxe1 16 Rxe1 fxg5 black would only lose one pawn and would keep the important pawns on e6, d7 which restrict the white bishop somewhat
- 17 ... Ke7!? blocks the bishop on f8. 17... Kf7 looks more natural
- 18 ... Rh6!? not a good square for the rook which does not have much space here. If you wanted to get out of the knight fork on g6, you could have played Kf7 which would also free the bishop on f8.
- 23 ... g4?? loses the game. White should have played Nf4 which protects g2 and at the same time attacks the rook on g6. Even if g4 did not lose immediately it does not look like a good choice as it seriously weakens the kingside, particularly the f3 pawn.

After 23 ... Bd6 white loses the queen and ends up with a piece vs queen and a rather passive position (particularly the knight on b1). There is no point to analyze this position as there are many ways to win this. An obvious plan could be to bring in the rooks via the open e-file to e2 or to win the pawn on f3 which seems very difficult to protect and once it is gone there are always mate threads on g2.

Comment: Is this analysis done through `stockfish`

Comment: @DevAnandSadasivam: No, through me. Stockfish would not give you any text-comments.

Comment: Is 23.Nf4 that much better? Doesn't 23...Bd6 and 24...Bxf4 win a piece?

Comment: @bof: White could play 24 Nxg6 Bxe5 25 Nxe5 getting rook and minor piece for the queen.